# Weights used in hook modifier affect texture created with an image

Tags: shader-nodes, vertex-weights

I am new to Blender, and probably my question has a very simple solution and has been done before, but I couldn't find a way to solve it (probably I didn't do the correct question in Google).

The situation is as follows:

1. I created a simple animation of a book opening following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=geyC6FfMFf8)
2. The critical part is that I used a Hook modifier that connects the pages to an empty to animate the page turn (with a SimpleDeform). The modifier uses a vertex group I created with the weights paint (see below).

[image]
[image]

3. I have a PNG file that I want to use to create the material. This PNG came from a real PDF that I converted to PNG for use as a texture. I include it using the texture node editor (see the 3rd picture to see the texture node editor). I use texture coordinates, mapping, and the image to use the PNG file.

[image]

4. The problem is (as I understand after making some proves) that the hook modifier, or the weights I used on it, affect how the image is introduced, as the following picture clearly shows:

[image]

Then, the question is: is there a way to use the weights for the hook modifier that doesn't affect the material/shader/texture?

Comment: i think, that the hook doesn't affect the image at all...but it affects the vertices. And the UV Map maps the UV "vertices" to the real vertices. And if the real vertices are stretched by the hook modifier, the image gets stretched too. So in my opinion you have to find a way, where you can bend your geometry without stretching. So i would recommend using a mathematical approach and maybe geometry nodes would be easiest to fulfill that task.

Comment: Hello, it should not affect the way the image is projected, it will just move the vertices

Comment: @moonboots the weighted _Hook_ permits stretching of the geometry? My first thought is, instead of deforming the page, deform a curve in the same way, and then deform the page along it, from a fixed origin at curve-start. The page would ride the curve without stretching along it.